# What is a good square monitor to use with a 2022 Macbook Pro?

Tags: monitors, macbook

I'm looking to try a square monitor.

I typically work with word documents, PDFs, spreadsheets and R.

My main complication is that a few monitors resulted in fuzzy text when combined with my 2022 Macbook Pro. I eventually settled on the Dell 27 inch ultrasharp (U2723QE) which was great. But now I want something that will be as crisp, but in a square shape.

Does it exist?